# What does this sentence mean "I may be wrong, but I highly doubt it. I'm Jackson"

Tags: slang

I don't have enough context to understand this sentence.
Is it a slang of US people ?

I may be wrong, but I highly doubt it. I'm Jackson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I may be wrong, but I highly doubt it. I'm **a** Jackson.

And here "Jackson" is a surname, which can be replaced by any surname: be it Smith, Jones, Futgvuff, Stroganoff,...

It is a meme, which  stems from the politically-opinionated book of former basketball star Charles Barkley entitled  *[I may be wrong but I doubt it](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/493922.I_May_Be_Wrong_but_I_Doubt_It)*.

Now its just a way of showing off your surname on t-shirt or sweatshirt.

Alternatively, in

> I may be wrong, but I highly doubt it. I'm Jackson.

*Jackson* could be a first name (example: Jackson Brown). The same meaning applies, whether the phrase is *a Jackson* or just *Jackson*.

Comment: So is this comparable to 'keeping up with the Joneses' in Britain? (in the way that it's based on surname obsession)

Comment: No @marcel that idiom means acquiring as many items as one's neighbor; this one means, either seriously or jokingly, that because of who I am (A Thompson, a Barkley, a Nixon, even a College Professor), I can't be wrong. It can be used ironically, suggesting that someone who is a Barkley or Nixon really can and probably is wrong.

Comment: Some of the hits on a Google search for “I may be wrong, but I highly doubt it. I'm" are followed by a name without an article.

Comment: Okay @Edwin I've factored that in.

Answer (score 1):

## You're 'perfect'

The first part:

> I may be wrong, but I highly doubt it

is then supported by the phrase

> I'm Jackson.

Which means (according to the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jackson)):

> A guy that's like crazy perfect. He's tall and strong and ...Overall, Jacksons are the best thing in the world...

Comment: Urban Dictionary entries for names are almost all in-jokes. They don't describe widely known traits associated with names.

Comment: @sumelic That may well be true. If so, it's too bad if UD isn't very reliable in these instances.

Answer (score 0):

It's a brag that has become enough of a catchphrase that merchandisers have picked it up for display on t-shirts and hoodies.

It means exactly what it says: "I concede that it is possible (in any given context) that I could be wrong, but that possibility is small." In other words, if we're arguing about something "I'm right".